# Prevent Opera from fetching page from cache on Back button or force to cache AJAX

Tags: jquery, browser, cross-browser, opera

I have a problem with 2 possible solutions.

1. How to force Opera to cache .ajax calls in jQuery?
2. How can i force Opera browser to reload page if user reaches it by clicking Back button?

Test scenario: open page, navigate any link, then return to the page via back button. Page is fetched from cache.

I've already read several articles( on StackOverflow as well ) and none of them are working:
1) Cache HTTP headers - ignored
2) Meta tags - ignored 
3) Solution with js onunload event and flag variable - doesnt work

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is it POST or GET?

Similar issue here: http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=435111

> Why Ajax request, using the GET method, cannot be cached in Opera?
>   Please look at this small test:
>
> http://www.karapuz.by/media/js/ajax-GET-caching-test.html
>
> It seems that Opera (mine is 10.10), in contrast to IE, FF, GC, and
>   Safari, is not caching the ajax response, even if it is explicitly
>   told to do that. Any ideas?

And the answer:

> It now seems that the problem is in the jQuery library.
>
> I made another test
>   http://www.karapuz.by/media/js/ajax-GET-caching-test2.html , it uses
>   more low level XHR object, not the jQuery's "ajax" as it was in the
>   first test. And now Opera is fine!